# Проекты ASP.NET в Visual Studio Express

Tags: c#, asp.net, ide

Здравствуйте, дали на руки ASP.NET проект, но у меня стоит Visual Studio Express C# 2010, и он не читает ASP, все перелазил, не могу найти, как подключить, или они несовместимы? И как работать с ASP, нужно Visual Web Dev. скачивать?

Comment: да нужно скачивать web dev

Comment: Вы сами ответили на свой вопрос!

Answer (score 1):

Нужно скачать и установить Visual Web Developer 2010 Express Этот набор инструментов работает с ASP.NET